# Can't get correct point position by 'latLngToLayerPoint' in leaflet grid canvas layer

Tags: leaflet

### How to reproduce

- Leaflet version I'm using: leaflet 1.0.0
- Browser (with version) I'm using: chrome 61
- OS/Platform (with version) I'm using: Windows 7
- Step 1：
  Open the [example](https://linghuam.github.io/test/20170922/index.html) in Google Chrome browser
- Step 2：
  Zoom the map

### What behavior I'm expecting and which behavior I'm seeing

**Problem Description：**
I inherit from 'L.TileLayer' and modify the method 'createTile' to create each tile using a canvas element. 
In 'createTile' method, I send an ajax to get each tile's data, which is a collection of latlngs.
In ajax callback, I get the data and translate the canvas's origin point. 
Finally, I use 'latLngToLayerPoint' to transform the latlng and draw it in canvas.

**Expected behavior:**
I expect to see the point is drawn on canvas and its position is correct.

**Actual behavior:**
I zoom the map, its position has offset.

### Minimal example reproducing the issue

http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/puguy/embed?html,css,js,output

```
// custom tile layer (asynchronous)
var ShipCanvasTileLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
    createTile: function (coords, done) {
        var tile = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'leaflet-tile');
        var size = this.getTileSize();
        tile.width = size.x;
        tile.height = size.y;

        // get tile latlngBounds
        var tilebounds = this._tileCoordsToBounds(coords);
        var topleft = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(tilebounds.getNorthWest());
        console.log('coords:[' + coords.x + ',' + coords.y + ',' + coords.z + ']');
        console.log('topleft:[' + topleft.x + ',' + topleft.y + ']');

        // send ajax (This is a test.In fact, I want to get data by each tile's latlngbounds! )
        $.getJSON('./data/test.json', function () {
            var ctx = tile.getContext('2d');
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, tile.width, tile.height);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.font = 'normal 36px Verdana';
            ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
            ctx.fillText(coords.x + ',' + coords.y + ',' + coords.z, 250, 250);
            ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 512, 512);
            // translate the origin point
            ctx.translate(-topleft.x, -topleft.y);
            var test_latlng = L.latLng(39, 116);
            if(tilebounds.contains(test_latlng)) {
                L.marker(test_latlng).addTo(this._map);
                var point = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(test_latlng);
                console.log('layerPoint:['+ point.x + ',' + point.y + ']');
                ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, 6, 0, Math.PI*2);
                ctx.fill();
            }
            ctx.restore();
            done(null, tile);
        }.bind(this));
        return tile;
    }
});
// add layer
new ShipCanvasTileLayer('', { tileSize: 512 }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I meet [This Problem](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3222)

The map method 'latLngToLayerPoint' use current map zoom, but in 'createTile' method, it use the old one.